# Why do we need Lack of Fit F-test?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

Why would I need lack of fit F-test to test the fit on the Data when performing regularization with cross validation gives me better performance measure of my model ? Why is F-Test still relevant when we have regularization ?

Comment: Why should regularizing the wrong model be useful?

Comment: you can use lasso for feature selection and then give the one that performs performs well on validation set . I don't see the need for Lack of Fit F-Test if i have good performance using CV.

Comment: A model can perform "well", depending on what "well" means, while still being a poor fit to the data.  A diagnostic that tells you the model fits poorly--especially if it tells you *how* it deviates from a good fit--could lead you to developing a much better model.

Comment: Isn't that the whole purpose of doing regularization i.e. to avoid overfitting to data ?

Comment: Yes, that's the main purpose: but it doesn't guarantee that the fit will be good.  If you aren't using the right model for the circumstance, regularization will not rescue you.

Comment: I don't see why would it not , if i the model that i am learning has the needed terms which means low bias and then variance can be brought down using regularization and why should i care much about the fit on train data anyway as long as it is not way too big. Lack of fit i guess is measured on train data only and if i am to fit the train data i can always reduce the error to 0. So why care about F-Test ?

Comment: Because nothing you assert is generally true.  You cannot always reduce the error to zero (in fact, that's usually impossible).  And if you *do* care about lack of fit if it is "way too big," then you have to estimate lack of fit to know whether that's the case!

Comment: Can't i fit a n degree polynomial to n+1 data points perfectly ?

Comment: Yes--but what do you suppose regularization and cross-validation would do when you attempt that?

Comment: It would prevent from overfitting the dataset and hence we would not get the perfect fit on data but hope to perform well on unseen data. lasso i guess would select the features and i can get the model that has lowest error on validation set.

Comment: @whuber It seems to me that this socratic dialogue could be recast as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The $F$-test considers all data points in one model. On the other hand, tuning a regularization hyperparameter through cross-validation requires data to be left out of the model-training process, data that could have been used to improve coefficient estimates. There are situations where data are not virtually infinite and are too precious to be used for something other than estimating regression coefficients.

Further, classical hypothesis tests are amenable to sample size calculations where you can know how many observations you need to collect to reliably detect an effect of interest. While you might be able to do something like this for regularized regression through simulation, it is not as straightorward.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?